# Derivative of $f(x,y)=x-y$, where $x,y\in\mathbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Suppose that $f:\mathbb R^2\times\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ is given by $f(x,y)=x-y$. How can I calculate the first and the second order derivative of $f$?

If $g:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$, the gradient vector and the Hessian matrix of $g$ are given by
$$
\nabla g(x)_i=\frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x_i}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\nabla^2g(x)_{ij}=\frac{\partial^2g(x)}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}
$$
for $i,j=1,\ldots,n$. But the function $f$ is defined on the Cartesian product $\mathbb R^2\times\mathbb R^2$. Is the Cartesian product $\mathbb R^2\times\mathbb R^2$ the same as $\mathbb R^4$ in some sense?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: @Clarinetist $f$ takes two two dimensional vectors and returns a two dimensional vector $x-y$. So $f:\mathbb R^2\times\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$. There are no typos.

Comment: Oh, sorry for the confusion. I'm used to seeing vectors as either with arrows or boldfaced.

Comment: Strictly speaking $\mathbf{R}^2 \times \mathbf{R}^2$ and $\mathbf{R}^4$ are not the same, but there is a canonical isomorphism between these two spaces.

Comment: @WillM. So there is a one-to-one correspondence between $\mathbb R^2\times\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^4$. There is a function $\tilde f:\mathbb R^4\to\mathbb R$ such that the value of $\tilde f$ is the same as the value of $f(x,y)$ when the argument is the same in this one-to-one correspondence sense. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: If $\varphi$ is an isomorphism between $\mathbf{R}^2 \times \mathbf{R}^2$ and $\mathbf{R}^4$ then you can take $\bar{f} = f \circ \varphi^{-1}:\mathbf{R}^4 \to \mathbf{R}^2.$

Comment: If I wanted to calculate the gradient of $\tilde f$, $\varphi$ would affect its value, right?

Comment: Chain rule, the derivative of $\varphi$ at any point is $\varphi.$

Comment: In regard to the gradient and Hessian, since your function is linear, its first derivative is just the function itself and then the second derivative is the zero bilinear function, the first derivative being constant.

Answer (score 2):

Use the definition: Fix $(x_,y)\in \mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R^2.$ You are looking for a linear transformation $T(x,y):\mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ that satisfies the property

$\tag1 f(x+h,y+k)=f(x,y)+T(x,y)(h,k)+r(h,k)\ \text{where}\ \frac{|r(h,k)|}{|(h,k)|}\to 0\ \text{as}\  (h,k)\to 0.$

It is easy to show that if $T(x,y)$ exists, it is unique, so all we have to do is find one such that satisfies $(1)$.

Set $T(x,y)(h,k)=h-k$ and substitute into $(1)$. After rearranging, we get

$r(h,k)=x+h-(y+k)-(x-y)-(x-y)-(h-k)=0$ so in fact, $T(x,y)$ satisfies $(1)$ so we have found our derivative. That is,

$\tag2 Df(x,y)=T(x,y)$

Notice that it is no harder to show in general that if $f$ is already linear, then its derivative is itself.

For the second derivative, we note that what $(2)$ says is that $Df$ is a function from $\mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R^2$ into $L(\mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R^2,\mathbb R^2).$ Therefore, $DDf(x,y)$ is the linear function that sends $(h,k)$ to a linear transformation $\mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ that satisfies

$\tag3 Df(x+h,y+k)=Df(x,y)+(DDf)(x,y))(h,k)+r(h,k)$

$$\text{where}\ \frac{|r(h,k)|}{|(h,k)|}\to 0\ \text{as}\  (h,k)\to 0.$$

Set $DDf(x,y)(h,k)=Df(x,y).$ Then, calculating as above, evaluating each term on $(h_1,k_1),$ we get

$\tag4 r(h,k)(h_1,k_1)=Df(x+h,y+k)(h_1,k_1)-Df(x,y)(h_1,k_1)-(DDf)(x,y))(h,k)(h_1,k_1)=0-(h_1-k_1)\to 0$

$$\text{as}\ |(h_1,k_1)|\to 0$$

and so again, we have found the second derivative because our choice satisfies the condition of the formula.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough answer! So the first derivative does not depend on $x$ or $y$ and maps $(h,k)$ to $h-k$. How does the second derivative look like? For each $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\times\mathbb R^2$ it should assign a linear map. We have that $DDf(x,y)(h,k)=Df(x,y)$. So this linear map is the first derivative? By the way, something seems not right with equation (4) ($=0$ does not seem to be in the right place).

Comment: Your function is linear so all the derivatives are basically the same. You just have to recognize that each successive derivative is a map from $\mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R^2$ into a space of transformations on the codomain of the previous derivative. The zero in equation 4 is where it should be I think. Note that $Df(x+h,y+k)$ and $Df(x,y)$ are the same function. (Why?)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, $f$ is not in the form of $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, so that definitions won't work. So what does the "first-order and second-order derivative" mean for you?

One option is to look at $(\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2, ||.||_1)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^2, ||.||_2)$ as normed spaces (with your favorite norms on them), and look at the [Fréchet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) of $f$.

Comment: Suppose that $(x,y),(h,k)\in\mathbb R^2\times\mathbb R^2$. Then
$$
\lim_{(h,k)\to0}\frac{\|x+h-y-k-(x-y+A(h,k))\|_{\mathbb R^2}}{\|(h,k)\|_{\mathbb R^2\times\mathbb R^2}}
=\lim_{(h,k)\to0}\frac{\|h-k-A(h,k)\|_{\mathbb R^2}}{\|(h,k)\|_{\mathbb R^2\times\mathbb R^2}}.
$$
How do we determine $A:\mathbb R^2\times\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$? If
$$
A(h,k)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}h_1&k_1\\h_2&k_2\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}a_1\\a_2\end{array}\right)
$$
and $a_1=1$, $a_2=-1$, the limit is $0$ since the numerator is equal to $0$. Does this make sense?

Comment: By the way, $A=(\begin{array}{cc}1&-1\end{array})^{\mathrm T}$ looks like the gradient of $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$, where $f(x,y)=x-y$. Is there a connection?

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb Yes, the derivative at $(x,y)$ is $(h,k) \mapsto h-k$. In the $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, the derivative "looks the same".